# Current Line For Visual Studio Macros

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms, macros

How can I read text of a current line (where cursor is situated) from Macros?

I'm going to use such a function:

```
 Public Sub AddTextToChangeLogFile()
    Dim textOnACurrentLine As ???
    textOnACurrentLine = ???

    If textOnACurrentLine.Text <> String.Empty Then
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter("C:\###\Changes.txt", True)
        sw.WriteLine(textOnACurrentLine + ". file: " + DTE.ActiveDocument.Name)
        sw.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Dim textOnACurrentLine As String
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.StartOfLine(0)
DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine(True)
textOnACurrentLine = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text
```

Comment: this has the side effect of leaving the line selected. A better option is to use na EditPoint

Answer (score 3):

Get the line index from the Selection and use an EditPoint, like this:

```
TextSelection text_selection = (TextSelection)m_DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection;
int line_index = text_selection.ActivePoint.Line;
TextDocument text_doc = (TextDocument)m_DTE.ActiveDocument.Object("");
EditPoint edit_point = text_doc.CreateEditPoint();
string line = edit_point.GetLines(line_index, line_index+1);
```